# Using Crystal Reports X I need to remove parts of a string

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

An example - The white rabbit (white rabbit) - what I need to achieve is to remove not only the words in the brackets but the brackets too so I end up with The white rabbit

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text is in a formula called MyText:

```
Split({@MyText},"(")[1]
+ 
Split({@MyText},")")[2]
```